# Excel formula to translate text in one column and show result in another column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am using Excel 2016 and have text in another language in column A (currently French but could be another in another spreadsheet) and I want to put a formula in e.g. cell B1 which will translate cell A1 and show the result in B1.  I then want to drag the formula down (if possible) so then this formula translates each cell in column and puts the result in the corresponding cell in column B e.g. B2 will have the translation in English for A2 and B3 will have the translation for A3 and so on...

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Translate text using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098260/translate-text-using-vba)

Comment: Did something similar years ago where we had to have 4 languages, so we had 5 columns, an index and 4 target columns, then just used vlookup according to which the user selected : had lots of help from the other nationalities to "polish" the equivalent translations!

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question:

> ### *"**Yes**"*

...it is definitely possible.