# Translating whole column contents to desired language(english )

Tags: excel, translation

I have an excel files which contains the name of the restaurant dish in Japanese. 
Its about 2000 Columns. 
 
Now I have to translate those words in three separate columns. Which are 
English , Chinese and Korean.

I translated the English part manually by using translation feature on Excel under review tab. 
However I had to copy , paste the translation one by one for each product which took a long time. 
I still have to do Korean and Chinese language. 
Is there any alternative way translate by using some translation + arrays ? Or any other options. 
My Files looks like this

```
Japanese |  English | Chinese   | Korean
たまご         Egg       ---        ---
```

Comment: see here how to do it with vba: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098260/translate-text-using-vba  you will then iterate the values and paste the new values in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully translated whole columns by using nifty addons of google docs called "Translate" 
All I had to do was, upload files to drive and open it with Google docs, then select the columns and go to addons, click translate(Which I just installed) and Vola.. Magic.