# excel translate function as formula

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible using excel vba to make a formula/function that can use the "new" translate function of excel so it could translate the text of a cell?
something like

=translate(from_language;to_language;A1) and the result the translated text.

thanks for the help

Comment: Excel has a inbuilt translate function: Review -> Translate.

Comment: you cannot use the review->translate in vba.  see this for work around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098260/translate-text-using-vba

Comment: I know, what i'm trying, is use that function in a formula, to automate the translation of the text is several cells!

Comment: How have you tried to convert the code to a UDF?  Please [edit] your post with your attempt and explain where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Excel feature into a VBA function, as in following very simple example (`&` means concatenation):

```
Function Do_Something(Target As Range)
  Do_Something = "Something: " & Target.Value
End Function
```

You can record a macro, in order to see how the translation is done in VBA, and turn this into a function.