# Google Translate function for Excel not working

Tags: excel, vba, google-translate

I have this function that translates all selected cells with Google Translate.

I was working fine for years but it suddenly stopped to work for some reason.

Any idea why? I'm using Excel 2010.

Thanks in advance

```
Sub TranslateCell()
        Dim getParam As String, trans As String, translateFrom As String, translateTo As String
        translateFrom = "en"
        translateTo = "fr"
        Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        Dim r As Range, cell As Range
        Set cell = Selection
        For Each cell In Selection.Cells
            getParam = ConvertToGet(cell.Value)
            URL = "https://translate.google.fr/m?hl=" & translateFrom & "&sl=" & translateFrom & "&tl=" & translateTo & "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & getParam
            objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
            objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
            objHTTP.send ("")
            If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "div dir=""ltr""") > 0 Then
                trans = RegexExecute(objHTTP.responseText, "div[^""]*?""ltr"".*?>(.+?)</div>")
                cell.Value = Clean(trans)
            Else
                MsgBox ("Error")
            End If
        Next cell
    End Sub
'----Used functions----
Function ConvertToGet(val As String)
    val = Replace(val, " ", "+")
    val = Replace(val, vbNewLine, "+")
    val = Replace(val, "(", "%28")
    val = Replace(val, ")", "%29")
    ConvertToGet = val
End Function
Function Clean(val As String)
    val = Replace(val, "&quot;", """")
    val = Replace(val, "%2C", ",")
    val = Replace(val, "&#39;", "'")
    Clean = val
End Function
Public Function RegexExecute(str As String, reg As String, _
                             Optional matchIndex As Long, _
                             Optional subMatchIndex As Long) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = reg
    regex.Global = Not (matchIndex = 0 And subMatchIndex = 0) 'For efficiency
    If regex.Test(str) Then
        Set matches = regex.Execute(str)
        RegexExecute = matches(matchIndex).SubMatches(subMatchIndex)
        Exit Function
    End If
ErrHandl:
    RegexExecute = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Comment: Please include the code for `ConvertToGet()` and `RegexExecute()` and `Clean()`.

Comment: Also, what happens? You say it doesn't work... but what happens? Does it produce an error... on which line?

Comment: Hi Excel hero. I just get the error message called by the Else statement.

Comment: Have you checked to see what `objHTTP.responseText` is when you reach that if statement? Does it still include `div dir="ltr"`? I'm guessing not, so that would mean that google changed something that you now have to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that Google has changed the response HTML and the DIV that your code is looking for for the translation is no longer part of the response format.

I ran and got a valid response page. I changed your code to work with this "new" response.

Try this:

```
Sub TranslateCell()
    Dim objHTTP As Object, URL$
    Dim getParam As String, trans As String, translateFrom As String, translateTo As String
    translateFrom = "en"
    translateTo = "fr"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    Dim r As Range, cell As Range
    Set cell = Selection
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        getParam = ConvertToGet(cell.Value)
        URL = "https://translate.google.fr/m?hl=" & translateFrom & "&sl=" & translateFrom & "&tl=" & translateTo & "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & getParam
        objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
        objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        objHTTP.Send
        'If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "div dir=""ltr""") > 0 Then
        If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "<div class=""result-container"">") Then
            'trans = RegexExecute(objHTTP.responseText, "div[^""]*?""ltr"".*?>(.+?)</div>")
            trans = RegexExecute(objHTTP.responseText, "div[^""]*?""result-container"".*?>(.+?)<\/div>")
            cell.Value = Clean(trans)
        Else
            MsgBox "Error"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: That was it! Now it's working properly again. Thank a lot, true Excel Hero indeed :)

Comment: @Marrone I found your question interesting and decided to create a User Defined Function based on this. I answered an ancient question here from 2013 just now using the UDF. You may find it useful:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65417789/3566998

Comment: Glad to hear that! I'll definitely make good use of that too. Thanks again :)